# Laravel text going out of paragraph

Tags: laravel

I wanna ask why my text goes out of paragraph? How can I fix it?

[1 Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0pAm.png)

[2 Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBaTV.png)

[3 Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AiQ6.png)

Comment: `.bgc-white p {word-wrap: break-word;}` should fix the issue for you.

Comment: use this post [https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-break](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-break)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a laravel issue. This is a style issue.
Try using following:

```
<p style="width:100%;word-break:break-word;">{{$product->body}}</p>
```